# How to Handle Listen FCM messages in the background?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-fcm

I have read the FCM firebase documentation for react native and I want to implement the FCM background on react native android.

But I'm still a little confused by the documentation

my code:

```
// @flow
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Optional flow type
import type { RemoteMessage } from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message: RemoteMessage) => {
    // handle your message

    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

How to trigger and implement it, Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: For this to be triggered, 1. Hide your app in the background. 2. Send a data only message to your phone (note: `priority` must be set as `high`)

Comment: Where dan How, you have a tutorial or link ?.

Comment: Data only message is a message without `notification` property. You could see here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices

Comment: Thanks, Tuan Huong is helpful.